# ViewState Encryption - Multiple sites on one server

Tags: asp.net

I have a web farm with multiple websites on each server. I am manually generating my validation and decryption keys. Can I use the same keys for different websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can; system.web has the [machinekey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28vs.71%29.aspx) element. MSDN has [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx#paght000007_machinekeyexplained) on how to set it, you will want to set the validation and decryption keys to be the same across all servers (but not the same key for both validation and decryption if you see what I mean).

You'll need to generate the keys, again MSDN has [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) for this.

If you want every website on the server to share a key (bad idea though), you can set the machinekey element in [machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and copy that onto each server in your farm.

Comment: Thanks. I've been through the article and used this tool to generate the key: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey Can you tell me why its a bad idea for each application (website) to use the same key?

Comment: Because then each web site could look at or decrypt viewstate and cookies from other web site. You want to keep web sites isolated from each other. Also, the more you use a key, the more chance there is of someone working out what the key is.